# Having formatting and highliting issues with vb.net win forms date-picker control

Tags: vb.net-2010, datetimepicker, datetime-format

In one of my windows application I've used Microsoft datepicker control. but just noticed that I've some issues in formatting and highlighting.  I've set the date format to `custom` and set the custom format to `dd/MM/yyyy`. it is showing selected date in correct format. but Today's date at the bottom of calendar control is showing in `MM/dd/yyyy` format. and when is place my mouse pointer on that bottom todaty date, it's not highlighting the last two digits of year.

To get a more clear view of the issue, please refer to the attached image... [image]

Answer (score 0):

Hi I get the same behavour in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1.

See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/70f53798-ceb0-4105-b1b3-4c72f5ae94f4/date-time-picker-custom-format-problem-with-t-or-tt

What version of Visual Studio and SP are you using?

Comment: I included the link as this seems to be a confirmed bug, the link goes to a post and provides a means to vote this bug up and hence fix it. Please don't vote it down.